# TWAIN: is it possible to open default preferences dialog?

Tags: c#, twain

I'm using custom c# wrapper around twain_32.dll for scanning and it is working fine. 
What I'm searching for is ability to open default preferences window for TWAIN source, similar to Source select made with DSMident. That way user could set default feed source for example and I would not have to scan with  ShowUI set to true...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following interfaces of TWAIN for your requirement:

- CAP_CUSTOMDSDATA
- DG_CONTROL / DAT_CUSTOMDSDATA / MSG_GET
- DG_CONTROL / DAT_CUSTOMDSDATA / MSG_SET